# javascript match() error in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems figuring out why IE8 doesn't like this:

```
//get all checked values from the checkboxes with the option_checkbox class
var values = $j('input:checkbox:checked.option_checkbox').map(function () { return this.value; }).get();
if (values.length>0){
  for (x in values){
    if(values[x].match("v")){ // <--this line causes a javascript error in IE8
      //do something here
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error:
"Object does not support this property or method"

I am thinking I should do some other sort of validation to verify type as perhaps map() and get() are not returning what I expect (a string with the value of that particular checkbox).

Any advice?

Comment: _"Any advice?"_ - Iterate over an array with a standard `for` loop rather than a `for..in`. You mention not being certain that `map()` and `get()` are returning strings - add `console.log(values[x])` in the loop and see what you get. (Or even `alert(values[x])`.)

Comment: If you're using jquery, you might as well use it well. Don't first create an array and then loop over it with a for. Use jquery: `$j('..').filter(function() { return /^v$/.test(this.value); }).each(..)`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the tips and help. I switched it to each in combination with indexOf and now it works in older IE version as well without fail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `indexOf`, it's [*negligibly faster*](http://jsfiddle.net/wXgAc/)*:*

```
if(values[x].indexOf("v") > -1) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: `!==` is useless in this case, because indexOf **always** returns an int.

Comment: @Rudie What are you all talking about? I meant use `!=` or `!==`, just not `>` .... sorry if my indiscriminate use of the non-type-casting version tripped you up :O

Comment: @Xander it's, as you phrased it, _negligibly faster_

Comment: @Xander did you try changing the execution order? Run one at a time, I think you'll find it affects the results **QUITE A LOT**. Seems to be about equivalent actually though, go Javascript.

Comment: @TheZ yes, though when increasing the repetitions, `>` is still fastest. http://jsfiddle.net/wXgAc/2/

Comment: @Xander I agree. Nice tests though, good to see empirical proof.

Answer (score 2):

try this instead:

```
values[x].match(/v/);
```